# Dynamic variable in mapped JSX Element

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I map an array in JSX and return a JSX element. I am trying to use dynamic variable while passing pageName in `usePageNameFormat()`. locale defined in component, so I have access to it.

```
<>
  {navigationData && navigationData[0].navItems.map((post,index) => 
    <Link 
     key={index}
     href={"/pages/" + usePageNameFormat(post.pageName.${locale})}>
      {post.pageName}
    </Link>
  )}
</>
```

I tried like above and also tried wrapping it with apostrophe, both gave me syntax errors.

Comment: So basically what you want is to use a variable's value as an object key. This is called a computed property, and the syntax for that is square brackets, i.e. `post.pageName[locale]`. You can see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names

Answer (score 0):

```
const formatPageName = (pageName) => usePageNameFormat(pageName, locale);

<>
  {navigationData &&
    navigationData[0].navItems.map((post, index) => {
      const formattedPageName = formatPageName(post.pageName);
      <Link key={index} href={`/pages/${formattedPageName}`}>
        {post.pageName}
      </Link>;
    })}
</>;
```

Try this one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).